ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'surya.model.segformer'
I have installed surya-ocr in my virtual environment. But whenever I am trying to execute the following code, I am getting this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'surya.model.segformer'
from surya.model.segformer import load_model, load_processor
model, processor = load_model(), load_processor()

I have also installed transformers, but still this is coming.
I was trying to follow the below code, but specifically for invoice extraction
https://github.com/srinathmkce/TheAIGuy/blob/main/ComputerVision/OCR/Surya-OCR.ipynb
Also it will be helpful if anyone could provide me some reference on how to use Surya-OCR or GOT-OCR for invoice extraction which has table values also.

Either you have not installed it correctly, or you are executing the code outside the environment, or there is in fact no module named surya.model.segformer. What do you want to ask us?

Can you confirm the module is installed by doing pip show surya-ocr from within the virtual environment (source .venv/bin/activate on nix)? Also your directory structure would be useful.

I have checked that surya-ocr is installed in the virtual environment.   I was trying to follow the following code, but use it for invoice extraction
https://github.com/srinathmkce/TheAIGuy/blob/main/ComputerVision/OCR/Surya-OCR.ipynb

py -m pip install surya-ocr  Released: Oct 14, 2024

Please double-check your module names. If they are not installed, you can install them using the command:
"pip install module_name"
Once installed, you should be able to import them without any issues. 
